# Validate particular field / particular rule using Kendo UI validation

Tags: javascript, validation, kendo-ui, kendo-validator

Current I have the following custom rules to validate fields of my form.

**Rules**

```
$scope.validator = $("#frmPreregistration").kendoValidator({
    rules: {
        varifySsn: function (input) {
            var ret = true;
            if (input.is("[name=last4Ssn]") && $scope.Last4DigitsSsn != undefined ) {
                ret = $scope.validateSsnLast4Digit();
            }
            return ret;
        },
        varifyDob: function (input) {
            var ret = true;
            if (input.is("[name=dob]") && $scope.DateOfBirth != undefined ) {
                ret = $scope.validateDateOfBirth();
            }
            return ret;
        },
        varifyZipCode: function (input) {
            var ret = true;
            if (input.is("[name=zipCode]") && $scope.ZipCode != undefined ) {
                ret = $scope.validateZipCode();
            };
        return ret;
        }
    },
    messages: {
        varifySsn: $scope.resources.SsnLast4DigitDoesNotMatch,
        varifyDob: $scope.resources.DobNotMatchWithSelectedUserType,
        varifyZipCode: $scope.resources.ZipCodeNotMatchWithSelectedUserType,
    }
}).data("kendoValidator");
```

I am validating the form whenever user enters a value in any of the field in the form by `$scope.validator.validate()`

This is resulting in firing the rules for all the fields even before the user enters any value into it.

**Question**
Is there any possibility that I can run a particular validation rule at a time or run validation for a particular field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `validateInput` for specific element.

**Example:**

```
$scope.validator.validateInput($("input[name=dob]"));
```

to hide invalid message you can use `hideMessages` function

```
$scope.validator.hideMessages();
```

Comment: is there a possibility to reset kendo validation with a function call like the solution or removing the `k-invalid` class is the only solution to do the validation reset?

Comment: the hideMessages() method is hiding the messages but the control's border is still red in color i.e. not removing the `k-invalid` class from the control, to do that is there a separate method?

Comment: i just realize that its not remove k-invalid class, I can not found Kendo API to do that. But you could use jQuery function like this `$(".k-invalid").removeClass("k-invalid")`